# How to show specific shipping options

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How can I show to my user on the checkout page a specific shipping option ?

I know how to remove a shipping option but I can't add a new one (an existing one) in $rates.

I tried to add :

```
array_push($rates, 'flat_rate:5');
```

Isn't array_push supposed to do the job ?

Here is a basic snippet, from my function files.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_package_rates', 10, 2 );
function custom_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {

    $total = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;

    if( $total < 100 ) {

      // remove from shipping options
      unset( $rates['advanced_free_shipping'] );

      // Tryed it but critical error is thrown
      array_push($rates, 'flat_rate:5');
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Tried everybit of code that I found on stack and other places, seems I'm the only one to have an issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$rates` is not a simple array, it contains also an object with data for each rate, so adding an array incl. the object is something you want to avoid. But you don't need to. Instead you can do it like this:

```
...
if( $total < 100 ) {
  // remove from shipping options
  unset( $rates['advanced_free_shipping'] );
}
else {
  // only available when total is <= 100
  unset( $rates['flat_rate:5'] );
}
...
```

It basically does the same.

Comment: Ah, I understand, thanks @Chrostip Schaejn. I thought that by try to push the correct rate id name it would take all the data from the object. My issue is that all my shipping options are already so complex (some for certain zip code, some for a distance, some with regular shipping weight ...), all of them already ruled by plugins. In your logic all shipping options are always visible and I just have to hide the one(s) I don't want to show, but in my case I need to inject some other shipping otpions, non-visible at first. Don't know if I'm clear enough and don't know if that is possible

Comment: you've opened in my brain some new connections, I was stuck in a  code oriented exit but I found another way to do the job. Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: I was stuck in the same issue, so hiding rates is easier than creating them by code (and a lot more easier to maintain). So good luck!